# How can i insert a span around every &

Tags: javascript, css, fonts, ampersand

I want to use the specific italic `&` in Adobe Caslon Pro, but only in the ampersand symbol.

What can I do to insert a `<span class="amp"`> around every `&` (ampersand)  so then apply the

```
font-style: italic;
```

to the `.amp` ?

Comment: Do you need to do this for your whole page or jsut for certain areas?

Comment: Look, here is my personal page, which is a wordpress installation, where im trying to do this, 
i´ve added a lot of & and &amps to see which one serves better

http://randirelen.cl/

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery to modify the HTML when the page loads:

```
$(function () {
    $("h1:contains('&')").each(function () {
        var that = $(this);
        that.html(that.html().replace(/&amp;/g, "<span class='amp'>&amp;</span>"))
    });
});
```

Note this only applies to h1 elements, modify it for the elements you want.

Comment: that.html i guess should be replaced with the page im in? but if there are multiple php pages, it should owrk how?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. But it will not bring you the solution you want to have, because only users that have adobe caslon pro installed on their system will see it in that font.

The only real option you have with special fonts is using an image. I don't think you want to use flash overlays or fight around with font-face.

Comment: +1 for raising the issue, but it is available on typekit now https://typekit.com/fonts/adobe-caslon-pro, as are most adobe fonts

Comment: You can also use CSS3 @font-face -- though that's not widely supported right now

Comment: @KOGI font-face is really widely supported, you just need to use the right method http://paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/

Comment: When I say not widely supported I am referring to older browsers that are still in very common use. Many users are still using browsers that do not support font-face. If you can control your audience's browser and require modern browsers, then font-face would be much more reliable

Answer (score 0):

This is quite an expensive operation to do client side as it means analysing and manipulating the DOM a lot. If your page is built using some server side scripting (or if you can add some) it's a much simpler affair... As the last thing the server does before the page is sent to the user do a regular expression replace on `&amp;`.

I'm no server side coder so can't tell you any syntax but it's going to be a lot more efficient and provide a slicker user experience than any javascript approach